# Segmenting video into different parts and unique rendering on each part then concat afterwards

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I currently have a very poorly performing application that splits up a video, renders it and the concats all rendered videos on android using ffmpeg

So I am running into issues with segmenting a video up into 5 parts at each different intervals/durations, rendering each video segment uniquely slowing up/speeding up and then finally concat all the segments back into one final video.

Currently I am doing each part separately -

Segmenting -
example for one segment
    -y -i pathIn -ss 0.0 -t 2.0 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -an pathOut

Rendering - example slowing down/speeding up
-y -i path -filter:v setpts=2.0*PTS pathOut

Concat -
-f concat -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -i input3.mp4 -i input4.mp4 -i input5.mp4 -c copy output.mp4

Right now I am running different separate thread for each editing of video, so 3, segment, rendering and concat.

I am trying to get this all done on one command ffmpeg line if at all possible, if not just the segmenting and rendering of the videos and kick of the concat cmd line later.

I am trying to emulate something similar to this https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

Comment: Are you trying to do this on Android?

Comment: Yes, sorry forgot to add that in